# How should I manage the AI in order to prepare promotion and migration of MFS files?

Tags: ab-initio

In order to prepare promotion and migration of MFS files, what are your recommendations on managing the AI_MFS parameter? This is often needed in standard promotion of dev>test>prod. It is also needed if the application is migrated to a system using a different MFS depth.

Should there be a different project parameter for the source or target MFS? If so, what name should it use?

Answer (score 0):

You can define custom parameters as input or output MFS directories on project level. The naming convention is up to you. These input and output MFS directories should be under the $AI_MFS directory.

The value of the AI_MFS parameter should be different in each environment (dev, test, prod).

Since it's impossible to answer your question correctly without knowing the details of your setup I suggest hiring someone for a short time (even for just 1 day) who could set up your environment according to your use cases/expectations.

(e.g. What do you mean by "promotion of dev>test>prod" exactly? If it means simply the promotion of the source code (projects) alone then just make sure that the AI_MFS is set to appropriate values in each environment (do this e.g. in the "stdenv" where the actual value of AI_MFS should be derived from some unix environment variable which is set up at login time).)